# SQL COUNT not showing result on PHP Table?

Tags: php, sql, list, select, count

My SQL table:

```
| user | bln | tipe |
|----- |-----| -----|
|  A   |  1  |  2   |
|  A   |  1  |  2   |
|  B   |  1  |  2   |
|  A   |  1  |  1   |
|  C   |  1  |  1   |
|  D   |  1  |  1   |
```

Using COUNT, in PHP I want to list the table like this:

```
| user |COUNT(tipe)|
|----- |-----------|
|  A   |  2  |
|  B   |  1  |
|  C   |  0  |
|  D   |  0  |
```

```php
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT user, COUNT(tipe) FROM keg where bln=1 and tipe=2 GROUP BY user order by id asc;");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0){
    echo '<tr><td colspan="8">Tidak ada data.</td></tr>';
}else{
    $no = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$no.'</td>
            <td>'.$row['user'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['tipe'].'</td>
        </tr>
        ';
        $no++;
    }
}
?>
```

But the table output is like this:

```
| user |COUNT(tipe)|
|----- |-----------|
|  A   |           |
|  B   |           |
```

Is my problem in `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)`?

I tried the SQL in an SQL windows and it's showing the output normally, but it doesn't in PHP.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($row);` inside the while loop, and you will see what the issue is. After that, go read up on what an _alias_ in SQL is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here. First, from the PHP side, you're trying to access the column `tipe` in the result set, but there is not such column - it's called `COUNT(tipe)`. This can be solved by using an alias.
Second, your `where` clause removes all the rows that don't have `bln=1 and tipe=2`, so you aren't getting any results for users C and D.
One solution would be to not use a `where` clause, but move the condition to a `case` expression for the `count` function to evaluate:

```sql
SELECT   user, COUNT(CASE WHEN bln = 1 AND tipe = 2 THEN 1 END) AS tipe
FROM     keg 
GROUP BY user 
ORDER BY id ASC;
```